# Cannot register commands in IoT Agent Fiware

Tags: fiware, agent, broker

I'm using IoT Agent with Ultralight run directly (not as a dockerized component). I'm able to register new device, which is mapped in Orion Context Broker. However I have an issue with registering Actuators which require commands within configuration data. I use:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://MYIP:4061/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "lamp003",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:003",
      "entity_type": "Lamp",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "MQTT",
      "commands": [
        {"name": "on","type": "command"},
        {"name": "off","type": "command"}
       ]}
  ]
}
```

And in response I'm hit with:

> op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceProvisioning | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a |
> msg=Device provisioning failed due to the following error:  |
> comp=IoTAgent Request error connecting to the Context Broker:
> {"code":"400","reasonPhrase":"Bad Request","details":"missing isDomain
> value for registration attribute"}

I tried adding "isDomain": "false" to elements of command table, but no luck. It used to work before and furthermore similar solution is presented on [official guide](https://fiware-iotagent-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stepbystep/).

Answer (score 1):

`isDomain` part of the **deprecated** NGSI-v1 syntax. It is not used in **NGSI-v2** or **NGSI-LD**

I think you may be running the IoT Agent as NGSI-v1.  You'll need to set `contextBroker.ngsiVersion` in your `config.js` or set the following [Env variable in Docker](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide/index.html#configuration-using-environment-variables) or Docker-compose.

```
IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2
```

`config.js`

```js
{
    host: '192.168.56.101',
    port: '1026',
    ngsiVersion: 'v2'
}
```

Comment: It's been a culprit for previous bug, but now I still cannot register commands. I get following error:
`{"name":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 501"}`
IotA is running in v2 ngsi version.

Registering devices without commands works fine. I'm running OCB as a default docker container.

Comment: Debug input from IotA:
`op=IoTAgentNGSI.Registration | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Registration error connecting to the Context Broker: 501 | comp=IoTAgent` 
_
`op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceProvisioning | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Device provisioning failed due to the following error:  | comp=IoTAgent Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 501`

Comment: As it's likely connected to OCB I added its configuration. OCB is running on different machine than IotA, but they are able to communicate (see registration of a sensor). Maybe I'm lacking some cross platform privileges?
  `orion:
        image: fiware/orion
        hostname: orion
        container_name: fiware-orion
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        expose:
            - "1026"
        ports:
            - "1026:1026"
        command: -dbhost mongodb`